Training T5 model on Spider and Gretelai dataset
I am working on this project for educational purposes. I definitely don't understand enough to find the flaw in my reasoning I expected textToSQL to be quite simple but here I am.
I want to build natural language to SQL queries agent and the model that seemed to be the most promising (both in reading and suggested by GPT) was the flan-t5 model. I intended to use the spider dataset, but after looking through it the data didn't seem to be enough so I added in the gretelai dataset by composing a common input format.
One thing about the format: I expected it to be more... general? For example I would expect to replace the name of the table with some kind of a placeholder so the model doesn't consider it and focuses only on the tokens that cause shift in the logic. Is there a better way than what i have displayed on the example?
I am considering adding a classifier which would enhance the data, for example I could try getting classifying the question into types of "simple_sql", "aggregation", "joins" etc. and giving that to the t5 model as extra metadata. Do you think that will matter?
I have been doing this mostly on the flan-t5-small model to speed the process up but have tried the flan-t5-base model on the most promising iteration with no significant improvements
Here is my code (from a jupyter notebook):
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_parquet("./data/gretel_train.parquet")
df_test = pd.read_parquet("./data/gretel_test.parquet")
df  = df[["id", "sql_prompt", "sql_context", "sql"]]
df_test  = df_test[["id", "sql_prompt", "sql_context", "sql"]]

import re

def split_on_top_level_commas(definition: str):
    segments = []
    current = []
    paren_depth = 0

    for char in definition:
        if char == '(':
            paren_depth += 1
            current.append(char)
        elif char == ')':
            paren_depth -= 1
            current.append(char)
        elif char == ',' and paren_depth == 0:
            segments.append("".join(current).strip())
            current = []
        else:
            current.append(char)

    if current:
        segments.append("".join(current).strip())

    return segments

def map_col_type(raw_type):
    t = raw_type.lower().strip()

    if re.match(r'^(int|integer|float|real|double|numeric|decimal|smallint|bigint)', t):
        return "number"

    if re.match(r'^(char|varchar|text|longtext|tinytext|mediumtext)', t):
        return "text"

    if re.match(r'^(date|datetime|timestamp|time)', t):
        return "date"

    return "unknown"

def parse_gretelai_context(sql_text: str) -> str:
    create_table_pattern = re.compile(
        r"CREATE\s+TABLE\s+(?:IF\s+NOT\s+EXISTS\s+)?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\s*\(\s*(.*)\)",
        re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL
    )

    statements = [stmt.strip() for stmt in sql_text.split(';') if stmt.strip()]

    schema_map = {}

    for stmt in statements:
        match = create_table_pattern.match(stmt)
        if not match:
            continue
        
        table_name = match.group(1).strip().lower()
        body = match.group(2).strip()

        schema_map[table_name] = {"columns": {}}

        col_defs = split_on_top_level_commas(body)

        for col_def in col_defs:
            fk_match = re.match(
                r"FOREIGN\s+KEY\s*\((?P<fk_col>[\w_]+)\)\s+REFERENCES\s+(?P<ref_table>[\w_]+)\s*\((?P<ref_col>[\w_]+)\)",
                col_def,
                flags=re.IGNORECASE
            )
            if fk_match:
                fk_col = fk_match.group('fk_col').lower()
                ref_table = fk_match.group('ref_table').lower()
                ref_col = fk_match.group('ref_col').lower()

                if fk_col in schema_map[table_name]["columns"]:
                    schema_map[table_name]["columns"][fk_col]["fk"] = (ref_table, ref_col)
                else:
                    schema_map[table_name]["columns"][fk_col] = {
                        "type": "unknown",
                        "is_pk": False,
                        "fk": (ref_table, ref_col)
                    }
                continue

            pk_constraint_match = re.match(
                r"PRIMARY\s+KEY\s*\((?P<pk_col>[\w_]+)\)",
                col_def,
                flags=re.IGNORECASE
            )
            if pk_constraint_match:
                pk_col = pk_constraint_match.group('pk_col').lower()
                if pk_col in schema_map[table_name]["columns"]:
                    schema_map[table_name]["columns"][pk_col]["is_pk"] = True
                else:
                    schema_map[table_name]["columns"][pk_col] = {
                        "type": "unknown",
                        "is_pk": True,
                        "fk": None
                    }
                continue

            parts = col_def.split(None, 1)
            if not parts:
                continue

            col_name = parts[0].lower()
            remainder = parts[1] if len(parts) > 1 else ""
            remainder = remainder.strip()

            is_pk = False
            if re.search(r'\bPRIMARY\s+KEY\b', remainder, flags=re.IGNORECASE):
                is_pk = True
                remainder = re.sub(r'\bPRIMARY\s+KEY\b', '', remainder, flags=re.IGNORECASE).strip()

            type_pattern = re.compile(r"^(?P<type>[A-Za-z]+(?:\(\d+(,\d+)?\))?)(?P<rest>.*)$")
            type_match = type_pattern.match(remainder.upper())
            if type_match:
                col_type = type_match.group('type').lower() 
                rest = type_match.group('rest').strip()   
            else:
                col_type = "unknown"
                rest = remainder.upper()
                
            col_type = map_col_type(col_type)
            if col_name not in schema_map[table_name]["columns"]:
                schema_map[table_name]["columns"][col_name] = {
                    "type": col_type,
                    "is_pk": is_pk,
                    "fk": None
                }
            else:
                schema_map[table_name]["columns"][col_name]["type"] = col_type
                schema_map[table_name]["columns"][col_name]["is_pk"] |= is_pk

    lines = ["<Schema>"]
    for table, table_info in schema_map.items():
        lines.append(f"-- Table: {table}")
        columns = table_info["columns"]
        for col_name in sorted(columns.keys()):
            col_type = columns[col_name]["type"]
            is_pk = columns[col_name]["is_pk"]
            fk = columns[col_name]["fk"]

            annotations = []
            if is_pk:
                annotations.append("PK")
            if fk is not None:
                ref_table, ref_col = fk
                annotations.append(f"FK -> {ref_table}.{ref_col}")

            ann_str = ""
            if annotations:
                ann_str = ", " + " ".join(annotations)

            lines.append(f"     - {col_name} ({col_type}{ann_str})")

        lines.append("")
    lines.append("</Schema>")

    return "\n".join(lines)

df["sql_context"] = df["sql_context"].apply(parse_gretelai_context)
df_test["sql_context"] = df_test["sql_context"].apply(parse_gretelai_context)

def convert_to_t5_input(user_query: str, schema_str: str) -> str:
    return f"""translate English to SQL:

<Query>
{user_query}
</Query>

{schema_str}
"""

def generate_t5_prompt(row):
    user_query = row['sql_prompt']
    schema_str = row['sql_context']
    return convert_to_t5_input(user_query, schema_str)

df['x'] = df.apply(generate_t5_prompt, axis=1)
df_test['x'] = df_test.apply(generate_t5_prompt, axis=1)

df['y'] = df['sql']
df_test['y'] = df_test['sql']

df_gretel_final = df[['x', 'y']].copy()
df_gretel_final_test = df_test[['x', 'y']].copy()

import pandas as pd

spider_df = pd.read_json("./spider/evaluation_examples/examples/train_spider.json")
test_spider_df = pd.read_json("./spider/evaluation_examples/examples/dev.json")
tables = pd.read_json("./spider/evaluation_examples/examples/tables.json")

def parse_spider_df(schema_info: dict) -> str:
    table_names = schema_info.get("table_names", [])
    column_names = schema_info.get("column_names", [])
    column_types = schema_info.get("column_types", [])
    primary_keys = schema_info.get("primary_keys", [])
    foreign_keys = schema_info.get("foreign_keys", [])

    table_to_columns = {i: [] for i in range(len(table_names))}
    for col_idx, (tbl_idx, col_name) in enumerate(column_names):
        if tbl_idx == -1:
            continue
        
        col_type = column_types[col_idx] if col_idx < len(column_types) else "text"
        table_to_columns[tbl_idx].append((col_name.replace(" ", "_"), col_type, col_idx))

    fk_map = {}
    for source_col, target_col in foreign_keys:
        fk_map[source_col] = target_col

    def get_col_annotations(col_idx: int) -> str:
        """
        Return a string describing if this column is a primary key or foreign key referencing something else.
        """
        annotations = []
        if col_idx in primary_keys:
            annotations.append("PK")
        if col_idx in fk_map:
            target_idx = fk_map[col_idx]
            t_tbl_idx, t_col_name = column_names[target_idx]
            t_col_name = t_col_name.replace(" ", "_")
            target_table = table_names[t_tbl_idx] if t_tbl_idx >= 0 else "unknown_table"
            target_table = target_table.replace(" ", "_")
            annotations.append(f"FK -> {target_table}.{t_col_name}")
        if annotations:
            return ", " + " ".join(annotations)
        else:
            return ""

    schema_lines = []
    for tbl_idx, tbl_name in enumerate(table_names):
        tbl_name = tbl_name.replace(" ", "_")
        schema_lines.append(f"-- Table: {tbl_name}")
        for (col_name, col_type, col_idx) in table_to_columns[tbl_idx]:
            anno = get_col_annotations(col_idx)
            schema_lines.append(f"     - {col_name} ({col_type}{anno})")
        schema_lines.append("")

    schema_str = "\n".join(schema_lines).rstrip()

    result = (
        "<Schema>\n"
        f"{schema_str}\n"
        "</Schema>\n"
    )

    return result

def convert_to_t5_input(user_query: str, schema_str: str) -> str:
    return f"""translate English to SQL:

<Query>
{user_query}
</Query>

{schema_str}
"""

def generate_t5_prompt(row):
    user_query = row['question']
    schema_str = row['schema']
    return convert_to_t5_input(user_query, schema_str)




contexts = tables[["db_id"]]
  
contexts["schema"] = tables.apply(
    lambda row: parse_spider_df(row),
    axis=1
)

spider_df = pd.merge(spider_df, contexts, on='db_id', how='left')
test_spider_df = pd.merge(test_spider_df, contexts, on='db_id', how='left')
spider_df['x'] = spider_df.apply(generate_t5_prompt, axis=1)
test_spider_df['x'] = spider_df.apply(generate_t5_prompt, axis=1)

spider_df['y'] = spider_df['query']
test_spider_df['y'] = test_spider_df['query']

df_final = spider_df[['x', 'y']].copy()
df_final_test = test_spider_df[['x', 'y']].copy()

from evaluate import load

training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="./flan_t5_modified_2.1_text2sql_results",
    learning_rate=2e-5,
    lr_scheduler_type="cosine_with_restarts",
    per_device_train_batch_size=4,
    num_train_epochs=5,
    weight_decay=0.02,
    warmup_steps=200,
    max_grad_norm=1.0,
    logging_steps=50,             
    save_steps=300,   
    gradient_accumulation_steps=2,
    report_to=["tensorboard"],       
    logging_dir="./logs",
    fp16=False,
    log_level="info",       
)

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=tokenized_dataset['train'],
    eval_dataset=tokenized_dataset['validation'],
    processing_class=tokenizer,
    callbacks=[EarlyStoppingCallback(early_stopping_patience=2, early_stopping_threshold=0.002)]
)

trainer.train()

And an example that results in SELECT rank FROM department WHERE MAX = MAX or something similar:
input_text = """
translate English to SQL:

<Query>
Find the largest ranking by selecting the MAX value.
</Query>

<Schema>
-- Table: department
     - department_id (number, PK)
     - name (text)
     - creation (text)
     - ranking (number)
     - budget_in_billions (number)
     - num_employees (number)

-- Table: head
     - head_id (number, PK)
     - name (text)
     - born_state (text)
     - age (number)

-- Table: management
     - department_id (number, PK FK -> department.department_id)
     - head_id (number, FK -> head.head_id)
     - temporary_acting (text)
</Schema>
"""

inputs = tokenizer(input_text, return_tensors="pt").to("mps")

outputs = model.generate(**inputs, max_length=1000)

print(tokenizer.decode(outputs[0], skip_special_tokens=True))
```

